# How to detect that one of the parameters in log.error is Throwable

Tags: java, log4j2, archunit

I am using log4j2 and logging the error as such:

```java
String param1 = "param1";
try {
  ...
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("This is an error: {}", param1, e);
}
```

This is my ArchUnit test, which tests that all the log.error calls contain throwable parameter:

```java
void errors_should_be_logged_with_context() {
    ArchRule rule =
        noClasses()
            .should(
                callMethodWhere(
                        target(name("error"))
                            .and(target(owner(assignableTo(Logger.class))))
                            .and(
                                target(
                                    rawParameterTypes(
                                        new DescribedPredicate<>(
                                            "logger.error without exception context") {
                                          @Override
                                          public boolean test(List<JavaClass> methodParameters) {
                                            boolean hasNoContext = methodParameters.size() <= 1;
                                            boolean hasNoExceptionInContext =
                                                methodParameters.stream()
                                                    .noneMatch(
                                                        j -> j.isAssignableTo(Throwable.class));
                                            return hasNoContext || hasNoExceptionInContext;
                                          }
                                        }))))
                    .as("use logger.error without context"));
    rule.check(ALL_CLASSES);
  }
```

The problem is that `j.isAssignableTo(Throwable.class))` is returning false for the parameter at index 2.

Test works as expected if there are only 2 parameters in log.error call (string, throwable).

How should the test be modified to cover both scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing the types of the parameters, not the type of the arguments.

[`Logger.error(String, Throwable)`](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#error-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-) exists as a method, but for more args than that, you're using plain Objects.

e.g. [`Logger.error(String, Object, Object)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#error-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-). Beyond 10 parameters, there's a varargs [`Logger.error(String, Object...)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#error-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) too.

The use of `rawParameterTypes` is wrong, but I'm not familiar enough with ArchUnit's API to say what to replace it with.

Comment: AFAIK, ArchUnit (as of the current version 1.0.1) does not offer an API about the actual method call arguments, so I fear that this cannot be solved right now.

Comment: I see. I'll try to dig into the API a bit more to see if that is possible.